# About the symmetric nature of Green's function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

What is the significance of *Green's function* being symmetric ? How do I understand this intuitively? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Answer depends on what you mean by "symmetry". The answer  given by user230715 seems to infer that the question refers to a symmetry of the domain, a geometric symmetry. But there's another symmetry even in the absence of geometric symmetries: Namely, $G(x,y)=G(y,x)$. This follows from $L G = \delta_{x-y}$ where $L$ is the given differential operator and $\delta_p$ is the Dirac distribution with support at $p$. In physics one interprets the $G(x,y)$ as the "force" exerted by $x$ on $y$ and this should be equal to the "force" $G(y,x)$ exerted by $y$ on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of the symmetry in Green's function is that it can be used to construct Green's functions using free space Green's function as its foundations.

One example of the use of the symmetric property is in proving that Poisson's formula $u$ on the half space $\mathbb{R}^n$ belongs to the space
\begin{equation*}
C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n_+)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})
\end{equation*}
(ie, smooth functions on the half plane extended to $L^{\infty}$ on the $n-1-$dimensional real numbers).

The intuition behind Green's function symmetry comes from odd/even functions. If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function, then we can write two functions 
\begin{equation*}
y(x)=f(x)-f(-x) \\
z(x)=f(x)+f(-x)
\end{equation*}
with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $z'(0)=0$. Observe that we can derive Dirichlet and Neumann type boundary conditions when we subtract mirror images of a function. This leads to the symmetry condition
\begin{equation*}
G(x,y)=G(y,x),~x,y\in\Omega,~x\neq y
\end{equation*}
where $\Omega$ is an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $G$ is Green's function.

Does that answer your question? I'll expand or clarify anything if you like.